# Porting from EXT js 3.4 to EXT js 5.0

Tags: extjs, extjs3, extjs5, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd

I have a web application on Sencha currently using ExtJS 3.4 functionality using the Sencha Architect 3.2, want to port/Migrate some forms to ExtJS 5.0.

What will be the changes required? they will be minor or Major ? Do I need to change whole structure to MVC ?

Quick reply will be appreciated.

Comment: I will suggest you to post same question in sencha support if you have produce License Login...You will get quick and better response there...

Comment: Means you have to upgrade your complete 3.4 application in to 5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from Ext JS 3.x to >= 4.x (in your case, 5.x) is a complete application rewrite.

In 4.0, Ext JS completely changed how the class system works (using syntax like `Ext.define()`) -- a breaking change so drastic that porting a 3.x app is just not possible. API changes abound, particularly the farther along you look into 5.x and 6.x. The use of Sencha Cmd will also be completely foreign to you.

Do you need to use MVC? No... but it's certainly a recommended practice. If you're considering Ext JS 5.x, MVVM also becomes an option.

My advice is to take a training class from Sencha to get up-to-speed on the latest-and-greatest things offered in Ext JS. Then start from scratch on a new version of your app; don't just try to port it from one version to another.