# How to upgrade Extjs 3 to Extjs 6

Tags: extjs, upgrade

I've been looking for some guidance how to upgrade Extjs ver 3 to ver 6 but without any luck. The only way I noticed from Sencha's site is to upgrade from one version up such as upgrade version from ver 3 to 4, 4 to 5 and then 5 to 6.

Comment: There is no simple "upgrade" - the differences between the two, in terms of the API, application architecture and toolset / SDK are so great that you are effectively talking about a complete rewrite of your project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Porting from EXT js 3.4 to EXT js 5.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491746/porting-from-ext-js-3-4-to-ext-js-5-0)

Answer (score 0):

See my answer to a similar SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491746/porting-from-ext-js-3-4-to-ext-js-5-0/33527912#33527912) -- Going from 3.x to 6.x is going to be a nightmare for you.

In all likelihood, you're much better off re-writing the application. There are far too many architectural and API changes to simply "upgrade" -- and honestly you wouldn't want to just blindly upgrade anyhow. Doing so would create an incredibly messy codebase and wouldn't follow "best practices" in the new version of Ext JS.

Besides, I hope you would have learned some lessons about your application in the years between writing it (in 3.x) and today. Presumably you have a much clearer idea of what the app does, you've added features since the original scope, and you have new things being planned... you would be doing yourself a huge disservice by not re-architecting the app to apply the lessons you learned about your own product/business.